# nginx with nginx-auth-ldap won't make

Tags: nginx, ldap, ubuntu-16.04

I've done this before and used this guide: https://calvin.me/nginx-ldap-http-authentication/

Unfortunately lately that server has had some major issues with nginx crashing (there have been no changes to the config lately);

```
    configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed\n',). Skipping.
/var/log/syslog.1:Nov 19 02:55:55 UB01 certbot[26093]: Error while running nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf -t.
/var/log/syslog.1:Nov 19 02:55:55 UB01 certbot[26093]: nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "ldap_server" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:35
/var/log/syslog.1:Nov 19 02:55:55 UB01 certbot[26093]: nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
/var/log/syslog.1:Nov 19 02:55:57 UB01 certbot[26093]: Error while running nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf -t.
/var/log/syslog.1:Nov 19 02:55:57 UB01 certbot[26093]: nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "ldap_server" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:35
/var/log/syslog.1:Nov 19 02:55:57 UB01 certbot[26093]: nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
/var/log/syslog.1:Nov 19 02:55:57 UB01 certbot[26093]: Attempting to renew cert (engtest.harrisisi.com) from /etc/letsencrypt/renewal/engtest.harrisisi.com.conf produced an unexpected error: The nginx plugin is not working; there may be problems with your existing configuration.
/var/log/syslog.1:Nov 19 02:55:57 UB01 certbot[26093]: The error was: MisconfigurationError('Error while running nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf -t.\n\nnginx: [emerg] unknown directive "ldap_server" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:35\nnginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed\n',). Skipping.
grep: /var/log/unattended-upgrades: Is a directory
grep: /var/log/upstart: Is a directory
user@computer:~$ sudo nginx -t
nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "ldap_server" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:35
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

I went and checked out nginx-auth-ldap and found that ngx_http_auth_ldap_module.c had changed greatly in size from what I previously had built from so I decided to pull down the latest everything and make an up to date installation of nginx and it's modules. Unfortunately the make appears to have gone very wrong when it hit nginx-auth-ldap. Not really sure what to do from here.

```
/home/user/nginx-auth-ldap//ngx_http_auth_ldap_module.c:3103:9: error: stray ‘\’ in program
/home/user/nginx-auth-ldap//ngx_http_auth_ldap_module.c:3300:9: error: stray ‘\’ in program
         <td id="LC619" class="blob-code blob-code-inner js-file-line">            <span class="pl-c1">ngx_conf_log_error</span>(NGX_LOG_EMERG, cf, <span class="pl-c1">0</span>, <span class="pl-s"><span class="pl-pds">&quot;</span>http_auth_ld
         ^
/home/user/nginx-auth-ldap//ngx_http_auth_ldap_module.c:3300:9: error: stray ‘\’ in program
/home/user/nginx-auth-ldap//ngx_http_auth_ldap_module.c:3333:71: error: stray ‘#’ in program
         <td id="LC627" class="blob-code blob-code-inner js-file-line">#<span class="pl-k">if</span> (NGX_OPENSSL)</td>
                                                                       ^
/home/user/nginx-auth-ldap//ngx_http_auth_ldap_module.c:3373:71: error: stray ‘#’ in program
         <td id="LC637" class="blob-code blob-code-inner js-file-line">#endif</td>
                                                                       ^
/home/user/nginx-auth-ldap//ngx_http_auth_ldap_module.c:3381:9: error: stray ‘\’ in program
         <td id="LC639" class="blob-code blob-code-inner js-file-line">        <span class="pl-c1">ngx_conf_log_error</span>(NGX_LOG_EMERG, cf, <span class="pl-c1">0</span>, <span class="pl-s"><span class="pl-pds">&quot;</span>http_auth_ldap:
         ^
/home/user/nginx-auth-ldap//ngx_http_auth_ldap_module.c:3397:72: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘<’ token
         <td id="LC643" class="blob-code blob-code-inner js-file-line">}</td>
                                                                        ^
/home/user/nginx-auth-ldap//ngx_http_auth_ldap_module.c:3627:72: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘<’ token
         <td id="LC699" class="blob-code blob-code-inner js-file-line">}</td>
                                                                        ^
/home/user/nginx-auth-ldap//ngx_http_auth_ldap_module.c:3727:72: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘<’ token
         <td id="LC723" class="blob-code blob-code-inner js-file-line">}</td>
                                                                        ^
/home/user/nginx-auth-ldap//ngx_http_auth_ldap_module.c:3823:72: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘<’ token
         <td id="LC746" class="blob-code blob-code-inner js-file-line">}</td>
                                                                        ^
/home/user/nginx-auth-ldap//ngx_http_auth_ldap_module.c:3911:72: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘<’ token
         <td id="LC767" class="blob-code blob-code-inner js-file-line">}</td>
                                                                        ^
/home/user/nginx-auth-ldap//ngx_http_auth_ldap_module.c:4040:72: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘<’ token
         <td id="LC798" class="blob-code blob-code-inner js-file-line">}</td>
                                                                        ^
/home/user/nginx-auth-ldap//ngx_http_auth_ldap_module.c:4106:72: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘<’ token
         <td id="LC814" class="blob-code blob-code-inner js-file-line">}</td>
                                                                        ^
/home/user/nginx-auth-ldap//ngx_http_auth_ldap_module.c:4177:72: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘<’ token
         <td id="LC831" class="blob-code blob-code-inner js-file-line">}</td>
                                                                        ^
/home/user/nginx-auth-ldap//ngx_http_auth_ldap_module.c:4270:72: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘<’ token
         <td id="LC853" class="blob-code blob-code-inner js-file-line">}</td>
                                                                        ^
/home/user/nginx-auth-ldap//ngx_http_auth_ldap_module.c:4354:72: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘<’ token
         <td id="LC873" class="blob-code blob-code-inner js-file-line">}</td>
                                                                        ^
/home/user/nginx-auth-ldap//ngx_http_auth_ldap_module.c:4543:72: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘<’ token
         <td id="LC918" class="blob-code blob-code-inner js-file-line">}</td>
                                                                        ^
/home/user/nginx-auth-ldap//ngx_http_auth_ldap_module.c:4677:72: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘<’ token
         <td id="LC950" class="blob-code blob-code-inner js-file-line">}</td>
                                                                        ^
/home/user/nginx-auth-ldap//ngx_http_auth_ldap_module.c:4764:72: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘<’ token
         <td id="LC971" class="blob-code blob-code-inner js-file-line">}</td>
                                                                        ^
/home/user/nginx-auth-ldap//ngx_http_auth_ldap_module.c:4807:72: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘<’ token
         <td id="LC981" class="blob-code blob-code-inner js-file-line">}</td>
                                                                        ^
/home/user/nginx-auth-ldap//ngx_http_auth_ldap_module.c:4858:72: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘<’ token
         <td id="LC993" class="blob-code blob-code-inner js-file-line">}</td>
                                                                        ^
/home/user/nginx-auth-ldap//ngx_http_auth_ldap_module.c:4934:73: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘<’ token
         <td id="LC1011" class="blob-code blob-code-inner js-file-line">}</td>
                                                                         ^
/home/user/nginx-auth-ldap//ngx_http_auth_ldap_module.c:5010:73: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘<’ token
         <td id="LC1029" class="blob-code blob-code-inner js-file-line">}</td>
                                                                         ^
/home/user/nginx-auth-ldap//ngx_http_auth_ldap_module.c:5082:73: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘<’ token
         <td id="LC1046" class="blob-code blob-code-inner js-file-line">}</td>
                                                                         ^
/home/user/nginx-auth-ldap//ngx_http_auth_ldap_module.c:5154:73: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘<’ token
         <td id="LC1063" class="blob-code blob-code-inner js-file-line">}</td>
                                                                         ^
/home/user/nginx-auth-ldap//ngx_http_auth_ldap_module.c:5195:74: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘<’ token
         <td id="LC1073" class="blob-code blob-code-inner js-file-line">};</td>
                                                                          ^
/home/user/nginx-auth-ldap//ngx_http_auth_ldap_module.c:5243:9: error: stray ‘\’ in program
         <td id="LC1084" class="blob-code blob-code-inner js-file-line">        <span class="pl-c1">ngx_log_debug1</span>(NGX_LOG_DEBUG_HTTP, c-&gt;<span class="pl-smi">log</span>, <span class="pl-c1">0</span>, <span class="pl-s"><span class="
         ^
/home/user/nginx-auth-ldap//ngx_http_auth_ldap_module.c:5243:9: error: stray ‘\’ in program
/home/user/nginx-auth-ldap//ngx_http_auth_ldap_module.c:5289:72: error: stray ‘#’ in program
         <td id="LC1095" class="blob-code blob-code-inner js-file-line">#<span class="pl-k">if</span> (NGX_OPENSSL)</td>
                                                                        ^
/home/user/nginx-auth-ldap//ngx_http_auth_ldap_module.c:5309:72: error: stray ‘#’ in program
         <td id="LC1100" class="blob-code blob-code-inner js-file-line">#<span class="pl-k">endif</span></td>
                                                                        ^
/home/user/nginx-auth-ldap//ngx_http_auth_ldap_module.c:5396:73: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘<’ token
         <td id="LC1121" class="blob-code blob-code-inner js-file-line">}</td>
                                                                         ^
/home/user/nginx-auth-ldap//ngx_http_auth_ldap_module.c:5417:9: error: stray ‘\’ in program
         <td id="LC1126" class="blob-code blob-code-inner js-file-line">    <span class="pl-c1">ngx_log_debug1</span>(NGX_LOG_DEBUG_HTTP, r-&gt;<span class="pl-smi">connection</span>-&gt;<span class="pl-smi">log</span>, <span class="pl-c1">0</
         ^
/home/user/nginx-auth-ldap//ngx_http_auth_ldap_module.c:5417:9: error: stray ‘\’ in program
/home/user/nginx-auth-ldap//ngx_http_auth_ldap_module.c:5429:73: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘<’ token
         <td id="LC1129" class="blob-code blob-code-inner js-file-line">}</td>
                                                                         ^
/home/user/nginx-auth-ldap//ngx_http_auth_ldap_module.c:5501:9: error: stray ‘\’ in program
         <td id="LC1146" class="blob-code blob-code-inner js-file-line">    <span class="pl-c1">ngx_log_debug1</span>(NGX_LOG_DEBUG_HTTP, ctx-&gt;<span class="pl-smi">r</span>-&gt;<span class="pl-smi">connection</span>-&gt;<span class="pl-smi"
         ^
/home/user/nginx-auth-ldap//ngx_http_auth_ldap_module.c:5501:9: error: stray ‘\’ in program
/home/user/nginx-auth-ldap//ngx_http_auth_ldap_module.c:5599:73: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘<’ token
         <td id="LC1170" class="blob-code blob-code-inner js-file-line">}</td>
                                                                         ^
/home/user/nginx-auth-ldap//ngx_http_auth_ldap_module.c:5629:9: error: stray ‘\’ in program
         <td id="LC1177" class="blob-code blob-code-inner js-file-line">    <span class="pl-c1">ngx_log_debug1</span>(NGX_LOG_DEBUG_HTTP, c-&gt;<span class="pl-smi">log</span>, <span class="pl-c1">0</span>, <span class="pl-s"><span class="pl-p
         ^
/home/user/nginx-auth-ldap//ngx_http_auth_ldap_module.c:5629:9: error: stray ‘\’ in program
/home/user/nginx-auth-ldap//ngx_http_auth_ldap_module.c:5695:73: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘<’ token
         <td id="LC1193" class="blob-code blob-code-inner js-file-line">}</td>
                                                                         ^
/home/user/nginx-auth-ldap//ngx_http_auth_ldap_module.c:5725:9: error: stray ‘\’ in program
         <td id="LC1200" class="blob-code blob-code-inner js-file-line">    <span class="pl-c1">ngx_log_debug1</span>(NGX_LOG_DEBUG_HTTP, c-&gt;<span class="pl-smi">log</span>, <span class="pl-c1">0</span>, <span class="pl-s"><span class="pl-p
         ^
/home/user/nginx-auth-ldap//ngx_http_auth_ldap_module.c:5725:9: error: stray ‘\’ in program
/home/user/nginx-auth-ldap//ngx_http_auth_ldap_module.c:5787:73: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘<’ token
         <td id="LC1215" class="blob-code blob-code-inner js-file-line">}</td>
                                                                         ^
/home/user/nginx-auth-ldap//ngx_http_auth_ldap_module.c:5829:73: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘<’ token
         <td id="LC1225" class="blob-code blob-code-inner js-file-line">}</td>
                                                                         ^
/home/user/nginx-auth-ldap//ngx_http_auth_ldap_module.c:5843:72: error: stray ‘#’ in program
         <td id="LC1228" class="blob-code blob-code-inner js-file-line">#<span class="pl-k">if</span> (NGX_OPENSSL)</td>
                                                                        ^
/home/user/nginx-auth-ldap//ngx_http_auth_ldap_module.c:5947:73: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘<’ token
         <td id="LC1253" class="blob-code blob-code-inner js-file-line">}</td>
                                                                         ^
/home/user/nginx-auth-ldap//ngx_http_auth_ldap_module.c:5951:72: error: stray ‘#’ in program
         <td id="LC1254" class="blob-code blob-code-inner js-file-line">#<span class="pl-k">endif</span></td>
                                                                        ^
/home/user/nginx-auth-ldap//ngx_http_auth_ldap_module.c:6024:9: error: stray ‘\’ in program
         <td id="LC1271" class="blob-code blob-code-inner js-file-line">    <span class="pl-c1">ngx_log_debug1</span>(NGX_LOG_DEBUG_HTTP, c-&gt;<span class="pl-smi">log</span>, <span class="pl-c1">0</span>, <span class="pl-s"><span class="pl-p
         ^
/home/user/nginx-auth-ldap//ngx_http_auth_ldap_module.c:6024:9: error: stray ‘\’ in program
/home/user/nginx-auth-ldap//ngx_http_auth_ldap_module.c:6217:73: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘<’ token
         <td id="LC1317" class="blob-code blob-code-inner js-file-line">}</td>
                                                                         ^
/home/user/nginx-auth-ldap//ngx_http_auth_ldap_module.c:6226:72: error: stray ‘#’ in program
         <td id="LC1319" class="blob-code blob-code-inner js-file-line">#<span class="pl-k">if</span> (NGX_OPENSSL)</td>
                                                                        ^
/home/user/nginx-auth-ldap//ngx_http_auth_ldap_module.c:6259:80: error: stray ‘#’ in program
         <td id="LC1327" class="blob-code blob-code-inner js-file-line">        #<span class="pl-k">if</span> OPENSSL_VERSION_NUMBER &gt;= 0x10002000</td>
                                                                                ^
/home/user/nginx-auth-ldap//ngx_http_auth_ldap_module.c:6362:180: error: stray ‘#’ in program
         <td id="LC1352" class="blob-code blob-code-inner js-file-line">                <span class="pl-s"><span class="pl-pds">&quot;</span>does not match address (neither server&#39;s domain nor IP in certificate&#39;s CN or SAN)<span class=
                                                                                                                                                                                    ^
/home/user/nginx-auth-ldap//ngx_http_auth_ldap_module.c:6362:215: error: stray ‘#’ in program
         <td id="LC1352" class="blob-code blob-code-inner js-file-line">                <span class="pl-s"><span class="pl-pds">&quot;</span>does not match address (neither server&#39;s domain nor IP in certificate&#39;s CN or SAN)<span class=
                                                                                                                                                                                                                       ^
/home/user/nginx-auth-ldap//ngx_http_auth_ldap_module.c:6366:9: error: stray ‘\’ in program
         <td id="LC1353" class="blob-code blob-code-inner js-file-line">                <span class="pl-c1">fprintf</span>(stderr, <span class="pl-s"><span class="pl-pds">&quot;</span>DEBUG: SSL cert domain mismatch<span class="pl-cce">\n</spa
         ^
/home/user/nginx-auth-ldap//ngx_http_auth_ldap_module.c:6406:80: error: stray ‘#’ in program
         <td id="LC1363" class="blob-code blob-code-inner js-file-line">        #<span class="pl-k">endif</span></td>
                                                                                ^
/home/user/nginx-auth-ldap//ngx_http_auth_ldap_module.c:6455:73: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘<’ token
         <td id="LC1375" class="blob-code blob-code-inner js-file-line">}</td>
                                                                         ^
/home/user/nginx-auth-ldap//ngx_http_auth_ldap_module.c:6472:180: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘<’ token
         <td id="LC1379" class="blob-code blob-code-inner js-file-line">{ <span class="pl-c1">ngx_http_auth_ldap_ssl_handshake_handler</span>(conn, <span class="pl-c1">1</span>); }</td>
                                                                                                                                                                                    ^
/home/user/nginx-auth-ldap//ngx_http_auth_ldap_module.c:6489:180: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘<’ token
         <td id="LC1383" class="blob-code blob-code-inner js-file-line">{ <span class="pl-c1">ngx_http_auth_ldap_ssl_handshake_handler</span>(conn, <span class="pl-c1">0</span>); }</td>
                                                                                                                                                                                    ^
/home/user/nginx-auth-ldap//ngx_http_auth_ldap_module.c:6498:225: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘<’ token
         <td id="LC1385" class="blob-code blob-code-inner js-file-line"><span class="pl-k">typedef</span> <span class="pl-smi">void</span> (*ngx_http_auth_ldap_ssl_callback)(<span class="pl-c1">ngx_connection_t</span> *conn);</td>
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 ^
/home/user/nginx-auth-ldap//ngx_http_auth_ldap_module.c:6590:72: error: stray ‘#’ in program
         <td id="LC1407" class="blob-code blob-code-inner js-file-line">#<span class="pl-k">if</span> (OPENSSL_VERSION_NUMBER &gt;= 0x10100000L)</td>
                                                                        ^
/home/user/nginx-auth-ldap//ngx_http_auth_ldap_module.c:6602:72: error: stray ‘#’ in program
         <td id="LC1410" class="blob-code blob-code-inner js-file-line">#<span class="pl-k">else</span></td>
                                                                        ^
/home/user/nginx-auth-ldap//ngx_http_auth_ldap_module.c:6614:72: error: stray ‘#’ in program
         <td id="LC1413" class="blob-code blob-code-inner js-file-line">#<span class="pl-k">endif</span></td>
                                                                        ^
/home/user/nginx-auth-ldap//ngx_http_auth_ldap_module.c:6650:72: error: stray ‘#’ in program
         <td id="LC1422" class="blob-code blob-code-inner js-file-line">#<span class="pl-k">if</span> (OPENSSL_VERSION_NUMBER &gt;= 0x10100000L)</td>
                                                                        ^
/home/user/nginx-auth-ldap//ngx_http_auth_ldap_module.c:6658:72: error: stray ‘#’ in program
         <td id="LC1424" class="blob-code blob-code-inner js-file-line">#<span class="pl-k">else</span></td>
                                                                        ^
/home/user/nginx-auth-ldap//ngx_http_auth_ldap_module.c:6666:72: error: stray ‘#’ in program
         <td id="LC1426" class="blob-code blob-code-inner js-file-line">#<span class="pl-k">endif</span></td>
                                                                        ^
/home/user/nginx-auth-ldap//ngx_http_auth_ldap_module.c:6765:73: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘<’ token
         <td id="LC1450" class="blob-code blob-code-inner js-file-line">}</td>
                                                                         ^
/home/user/nginx-auth-ldap//ngx_http_auth_ldap_module.c:6769:72: error: stray ‘#’ in program
         <td id="LC1451" class="blob-code blob-code-inner js-file-line">#<span class="pl-k">endif</span></td>
                                                                        ^
/home/user/nginx-auth-ldap//ngx_http_auth_ldap_module.c:6875:72: error: stray ‘#’ in program
         <td id="LC1476" class="blob-code blob-code-inner js-file-line">#<span class="pl-k">if</span> (NGX_OPENSSL)</td>
                                                                        ^
/home/user/nginx-auth-ldap//ngx_http_auth_ldap_module.c:6895:72: error: stray ‘#’ in program
         <td id="LC1481" class="blob-code blob-code-inner js-file-line">#<span class="pl-k">endif</span></td>
                                                                        ^
/home/user/nginx-auth-ldap//ngx_http_auth_ldap_module.c:6908:73: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘<’ token
         <td id="LC1484" class="blob-code blob-code-inner js-file-line">}</td>
                                                                         ^
/home/user/nginx-auth-ldap//ngx_http_auth_ldap_module.c:7084:9: error: stray ‘\’ in program
         <td id="LC1526" class="blob-code blob-code-inner js-file-line">            <span class="pl-k">if</span> (rc == LDAP_SERVER_DOWN &amp;&amp; \</td>
         ^
/home/user/nginx-auth-ldap//ngx_http_auth_ldap_module.c:7406:9: error: stray ‘\’ in program
         <td id="LC1605" class="blob-code blob-code-inner js-file-line">                            <span class="pl-c1">ngx_log_debug1</span>(NGX_LOG_DEBUG_HTTP, c-&gt;<span class="pl-smi">log</span>, <span class="pl-c1">0</span>, <span class=
         ^
/home/user/nginx-auth-ldap//ngx_http_auth_ldap_module.c:7406:9: error: stray ‘\’ in program
/home/user/nginx-auth-ldap//ngx_http_auth_ldap_module.c:7550:73: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘<’ token
         <td id="LC1640" class="blob-code blob-code-inner js-file-line">}</td>
                                                                         ^
/home/user/nginx-auth-ldap//ngx_http_auth_ldap_module.c:7601:9: error: stray ‘\’ in program
         <td id="LC1652" class="blob-code blob-code-inner js-file-line">    <span class="pl-c1">ngx_log_debug1</span>(NGX_LOG_DEBUG_HTTP, c-&gt;<span class="pl-smi">log</span>, <span class="pl-c1">0</span>, <span class="pl-s"><span class="pl-p
         ^
/home/user/nginx-auth-ldap//ngx_http_auth_ldap_module.c:7601:9: error: stray ‘\’ in program
/home/user/nginx-auth-ldap//ngx_http_auth_ldap_module.c:7659:9: error: stray ‘\’ in program
         <td id="LC1666" class="blob-code blob-code-inner js-file-line">        <span class="pl-c1">ngx_log_error</span>(NGX_LOG_ERR, c-&gt;<span class="pl-smi">log</span>, <span class="pl-c1">0</span>, <span class="pl-s"><span class="pl-pds">
         ^

/home/user/nginx-auth-ldap//ngx_http_auth_ldap_module.c:10029:9: error: stray ‘\’ in program
/home/user/nginx-auth-ldap//ngx_http_auth_ldap_module.c:10102:73: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘<’ token
         <td id="LC2256" class="blob-code blob-code-inner js-file-line">}</td>
                                                                         ^
/home/user/nginx-auth-ldap//ngx_http_auth_ldap_module.c:10292:73: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘<’ token
         <td id="LC2302" class="blob-code blob-code-inner js-file-line">}</td>
                                                                         ^
/home/user/nginx-auth-ldap//ngx_http_auth_ldap_module.c:10461:73: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘<’ token
         <td id="LC2343" class="blob-code blob-code-inner js-file-line">}</td>
                                                                         ^
/home/user/nginx-auth-ldap//ngx_http_auth_ldap_module.c:10488:12: error: missing terminating ' character [-Werror]
       <!-- '"` --><!-- </textarea></xmp> --></option></form><form class="js-jump-to-line-form Box-body d-flex" action="" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="get"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" />
            ^
/home/user/nginx-auth-ldap//ngx_http_auth_ldap_module.c:10488:7: error: missing terminating ' character
       <!-- '"` --><!-- </textarea></xmp> --></option></form><form class="js-jump-to-line-form Box-body d-flex" action="" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="get"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" />
       ^
/home/user/nginx-auth-ldap//ngx_http_auth_ldap_module.c:10508:31: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before numeric constant
       <li class="mr-3">&copy; 2018 <span title="0.14099s from unicorn-7c98f94446-7tvwk">GitHub</span>, Inc.</li>
                               ^
/home/user/nginx-auth-ldap//ngx_http_auth_ldap_module.c:10541:5: error: stray ‘\342’ in program
     You can’t perform that action at this time.
     ^
/home/user/nginx-auth-ldap//ngx_http_auth_ldap_module.c:10541:5: error: stray ‘\200’ in program
/home/user/nginx-auth-ldap//ngx_http_auth_ldap_module.c:10541:5: error: stray ‘\231’ in program
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
objs/Makefile:1250: recipe for target 'objs/addon/nginx-auth-ldap/ngx_http_auth_ldap_module.o' failed
make[1]: *** [objs/addon/nginx-auth-ldap/ngx_http_auth_ldap_module.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/user/nginx-1.14.1'
Makefile:8: recipe for target 'build' failed
make: *** [build] Error 2
user@computer:~/nginx-1.14.1$
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to compile a web page, not source code. Go back to wherever you got that file, and try again.